# Identifying board revision(s)

Tags: pcb-design

Like many others today, I am having to make some pretty serious changes to an existing design to make it viable for manufacture. It is essential that my firmware work between the original board revision and the newer board revision with different components, so I'm wondering what the best method of identifying the board revision may be? Below are some of the ideas I've had already.

- Store a flag in the built-in EEPROM and program the revision when the unit is being provisioned. The biggest "con" here is that the EEPROM isn't exactly immutable, and I don't want a bug to end up causing chaos in the firmware.
- Pull up some unused I/O pins on the newer revision. My worry with this is that the pins are floating on the original revision, so I assume I will get inconsistent results here.

For reference, I am using a PIC24FJ1024GA606 MCU.

Comment: *My worry with this is that the pins are floating on the original revision* - can you enable internal pull-ups/downs?

Comment: Change the firmware to use weak internal pull downs and use stronger external pull ups in the new board

Comment: Io space is a premium, generally you deal with the headache of some kind of prom but as a retrofit or just because using a spare io is also commonly seen

Comment: Thanks @Passerby. The PIC24FJ has PU/PD functionality for the Int-on-change functionality, but it looks like I can just enable those PU/PDs without actually making use of IOC, which should do the trick!

Comment: Do this with at least two I/O pins (if available) so you can identify 4 revisions.

Comment: Can your firmware do a self test to drive unused inputs and readback the result to see if it is pulled in one direction?

Comment: You mentioned "to make it viable for manufacture", does it means the original board is some R&D prototype? In which case, you should seriously consider whether it is worth keep supporting the old version. It's a lot of extra work/code added, maintenance, bugs, build, etc...

Comment: @Damien - By "to make it viable for manufacture", I mean "to allow it to use parts that aren't out of stock for the next 40 weeks", lol.

Comment: @t3ddftw I feel your pain, having the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, you can use weak internal pull resistors and stronger external pull resistors. If you calculate it properly, the externals will override the internal resistors (with minimal current draw). You can then read the state to identify what revision board is used. To zero out the current draw, you could then switch the gpio to the same state of the external resistors or just go high impedance.

That said, most microcontroller manufacturers have a recommendation to set unused gpio to a specific state to minimize issues re: floating pins, noise, current draw, register usage, etc. Microchip generally recommends drive them output low, alternatively with a ~10k pull down, or input with a pull resistor to either vss or vcc.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an external resistor to define a pin state (or short to supply or ground directly) on unused pin. Or multiple pins. Enable internal pull resistors and set the external resistor to pull to opposite state. If an ADC pin is available there can be multiple bits defined by a pin.

But just like the EEPROM is not 100% reliable, neither ate the resistors - there can be manufacturing errors or a resistor can get loose during transport to customer. Pick your challenge - if the MCU contains OTP memory then you could program it during manufacture and only read during boot.

Comment: Using OTP memory identifies the MCU, not the board. If the MCU is damaged and needs replacing, the value OTP cannot be read for programming into the replacement. That's a well-trodden weakness of that scheme.

Comment: If the resistor gets loose in transit you probably have Bigger issues

Answer (score 0):

See if your chip has options bytes.

If not, use the eeprom approach, but make sure to have your software do nothing else if the board revision is unconfigured or incorrect (checksum). That would prevent your "bug".